# Is it possible to dynamically change a label in ProgressTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

So I currently have this chunk of code:

```
<progresstemplate>
        <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
        <div id="processMessage"> Loading...
        <asp:Label ID="lblProgressMessage" runat="server" Text="Loading..."></asp:Label>
        </div>
</progresstemplate>
```

Once 'Button1' is clicked, it will call `Button1_Click` in the code behind. There can be a lot of things going on, so I want to display to the user where the method it at by changing `lblProgressMessage` to reflect what exactly is loading. Is this possible? Most solutions I find seem to only involve changing `ProgressTemplate` on `Page_Load`, which is no good since I need to to be updated relative to what is happening during a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Probably not without asynchronously poling the server for updates or something like [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) that would allow the server to push updates to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use AJAX to call the server and grab the progress data from a shared state, such as session.

You can do this with JQuery and a simple HttpHandler that returns process as XML. There's a walk through of how this all fits together [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170882/jQuery-AJAX-and-HttpHandlers-in-ASP-NET).